# Trying to change colors on a Python gauge using PYGame

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I am trying to use this gauge as a speedometer or tachometer.  Right now it acts more like a fuel gauge.  I am finding changing the colors challenging .  The code is not well commented.  If there are better ways to go about this, better coding tools, libraries and methods to create an assortment of animated gauges,  I am interested.  I am running this on the latest Debian using Python 3.7 .   Any ideas are much appropriated.   It is taking data from the USB port.  I added random routine as well.

```
import pygame as py
import pygame.gfxdraw
import math
import serial
from random import randint

#ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)

class Gauge:

    def __init__(self, screen, FONT, x_cord, y_cord, thickness, radius, circle_colour, glow=True):
        self.screen = screen
        self.Font = FONT
        self.x_cord = x_cord
        self.y_cord = y_cord
        self.thickness = thickness
        self.radius = radius
        self.circle_colour = circle_colour
        self.glow = glow

    def draw(self, percent):
        fill_angle = int(percent*270/100)
        per=percent
        if percent > 100:
            percent = 100
        if per <=40:
            per=0
        if per > 100:
            per = 100
        ac = [int(255-per*255/100),int(per*255/100),int(0), 255]
        for indexi in range(len(ac)):
            if ac[indexi] < 0:
                ac[indexi] = 0
            if ac[indexi] > 255:
                ac[indexi] = 255
        print(ac)
        pertext = self.Font.render(str(percent) + "%", True, ac)
        pertext_rect = pertext.get_rect(center=(int(self.x_cord), int(self.y_cord)))
        self.screen.blit(pertext, pertext_rect)
        for i in range(0, self.thickness):
            pygame.gfxdraw.arc(screen, int(self.x_cord), int(self.y_cord), self.radius - i, -225, 270 - 225, self.circle_colour)
            if percent >4:
                pygame.gfxdraw.arc(screen, int(self.x_cord), int(self.y_cord), self.radius - i, -225, fill_angle - 225-8, ac)
        if percent < 4:
            return
        if self.glow:
            for i in range(0,15):
                ac [3] = int(150 - i*10)
                pygame.gfxdraw.arc(screen, int(self.x_cord), int(self.y_cord), self.radius + i, -225, fill_angle - 225-8, ac)
            for i in range(0,15):
                ac [3] = int(150 - i*10)
                pygame.gfxdraw.arc(screen, int(self.x_cord), int(self.y_cord), self.radius -self.thickness - i, -225, fill_angle - 225-8, ac)
            angle_r = math.radians(fill_angle-225-8)
            lx,ly = int((self.radius-self.thickness/2)*math.cos(angle_r)), int( (self.radius-self.thickness/2)*math.sin(angle_r))
            ac[3] = 255
            lx = int(lx+self.x_cord)
            ly = int(ly + self.y_cord)
            pygame.draw.circle(self.screen,ac,(lx,ly),int(self.thickness/2),0)
            for i in range(0,10):
                ac [3] = int(150 - i*15)
                pygame.gfxdraw.arc(screen, int(lx), int(ly), (self.thickness//2)+i , fill_angle -225-10, fill_angle - 225-180-10, ac)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bg_c = (56, 56, 56)
#    circle_c = (55, 77, 91)
    circle_c = (126, 245, 95)

    pygame.init()
    #width, height = (640, 480)
    width = 640
    height = 480
    background = py.image.load("gaugebg.png") ## Load the image file
    background = py.transform.scale(background,(630,520)) ## Make it the same size as the screen
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Wahaj Gauge Pygame')
    fps = 6
    FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('ARIAL', 75)
    my_gauge = Gauge(
        screen=screen,
        FONT=FONT,
        x_cord=width / 2,
        y_cord=height / 2,
        thickness=50,
        radius=200,
        circle_colour=circle_c,
        glow=False)
    percentage = 0
    ifdelay = 0
    while True:
        # FOR SHOWING CHANGE IN GAUGE
     # rangauge = ser.readline()
     # percentage = int(rangauge)
      screen.blit(background,(0,0)) ## Blit the background onto the screen first
      percentage=randint(77, 84)
           # percentage = 0
         #       screen.fill(bg_c)
      #my_gauge.draw(percent=20)
      my_gauge.draw(percent=percentage)
      pygame.display.update()
      clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: *"I am trying to get `background_image = pygame.image.load('gaugebg.png')` to work."* - So please show us 'gaugebg.png'.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I was able to get the background image working and clear up the other issue with the percentile.   The only issue remaining is the changing the color of the animated part of the gauge.   Sorry  for my lapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color of the gauge is defined by the line

> ```py
> ac = [int(255-per*255/100),int(per*255/100),int(0), 255]
> ```

Choose different color or define the color in dependency of `self.circle_colour`. Play around with different functions:

```py
ac = [int(self.circle_colour[0] * per/100),
      int(self.circle_colour[1] * per/100),
      int(self.circle_colour[2] * per/100)]
```

or

```py
ac = [255-int(self.circle_colour[0] * per/100),
      255-int(self.circle_colour[1] * per/100),
      255-int(self.circle_colour[2] * per/100)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarity.   Much appreciated!  Sometimes a little verbosity in one's code goes a long way in making things easier to understand.